# How to do client-side load balancing of a GRPC service hosted inside a Kubernetes cluster from outside a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, azure-aks, grpc-go

**Scenario**: We have a client *outside* a K8s cluster trying to access a GRPC service hosted *inside* a K8s cluster. Both the client and the service are part of the same VNET in Azure. We would like to use `client-side load balancing` for accessing this GRPC service.

**Setup of our K8s cluster**: Our K8s cluster is hosted inside an Azure VNET and uses `Azure CNI` networking model, so this means the pods in our cluster have the IP addresses from the VNET's IP address space. Please note we are *not* using AKS and are self-hosting the K8s cluster, but this whole question should not depend on this in my opinion.

**Questions**:

- We would like to use `client-side load balancing` for accessing this GRPC service. If both our client and server were present inside the K8s cluster, then we could have used K8s `headless service` to get list of IP addresses. But in this case since client is outside the K8s cluster, we are looking for solutions on how to retrieve the IP addresses outside the K8s cluster?
- Can K8s cluster create DNS records in a DNS server which is hosted outside the K8s cluster so that the client which is outside the K8s cluster can access the list of IP addresses from it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: We are using version `v1.20.7` and yes we are using bare metal installation. We created our cluster using `aks-engine` (https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine).

Comment: Seems like one option for me is to just query the kubernetes api to get list of endpoints.

Comment: You are using deprecated version of K8s. Is it possible to upgrade it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could solve the issue by using [Extenral DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns). After wiring up my cluster with External DNS (which was linked to a Azure Private DNS zone), I created a `headless service` and found that on deployment of this service, DNS records were created in the Azure Private DNS zone. I was able to get the list of IP addresses of the pods by just doing a DNS lookup of the service's DNS name.